# Wordpress multisite - is it possible to have different taxonomies for each site?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, multisite, taxonomy

In my wordpress multisite install I have a case studies custom post type set up and they have custom taxonomies. This is all working well, however I need to create different taxonomies for the case studies custom post type across different sites.

I can see many articles about sharing/global taxonomies but nothing about having different taxonomies on different sites.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can.

Each site in multisite is completely independent, so you can have completely different CPTs, taxonomies and... everything.

The problem is that if you register the CPT via a plugin, and you enable it in all sites (or network-activate it) and you use the same plugin to register taxonomies, you'll have same taxonomies everywhere.

The simplest thing would be to create a plugin to register the CPT and taxonomies that you want in all sites (if any), then network-activate it.

After that, you can create different plugin for different taxonomies.

For example, if you "main" plugin does:

```
add_action('init', function() {
   register_post_type( 'mycpt', [ ... ] );
});
```

You can have *another* plugin that does:

```
add_action('registered_post_type', function($cpt) {
   if ( $cpt !== 'mycpt' ) {
       return;
   }
   register_taxonomy( 'taxonomy_1', 'mycpt', [ ... ] );
   register_taxonomy( 'taxonomy_2', 'mycpt', [ ... ] );
});
```

then, another that does:

```
add_action('registered_post_type', function($cpt) {
   if ( $cpt !== 'mycpt' ) {
       return;
   }
   register_taxonomy( 'taxonomy_3', 'mycpt', [ ... ] );
});
```

So you can activate on specific sites the plugins that activate the taxonomies you need.

Thanks to the fact that you use `registered_post_type` action, if the "main" plugin is not activated, even if the secondary plugin are activated they will do nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @gmazzap - the custom post types are setup in the code and so are the taxonomies, I'm assuming if I set the custom taxonomies in the code they will be available globally but with your approach they are individual to each site, is that correct?

Comment: Yes @NeelamKhan if custom taxonomies are set in different plugin and you enable different plugin in different websites, you'll end up having taxonomies where you need them.